# KMO test in SPSS

Tags: spss, factor-analysis

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of observations and variables. A snippet of my spreadsheet can be seen below:

```
             filename   wordcount able about actually again almost
             salvia_001   1582     2      2     0       8     2
             salvia_002   1618     0      2     2       2     1
             salvia_003   1144     0      1     0       0     1
```

As you can see above, filename is the name of the text, wordcount is how many words there are in the text and the other variables are the frequency of each word in the texts.
It´s necessary to normalize their frequencies, so I divided the  frequency of the word variables by the variable wordcount and multiplied by `1000` **(e.g., able = 2 -> 2/1582x1000 = 1.26 and son on)**.
Well, when I run an unrotated factor analysis in SPSS, the KMO is mediocre `(0.412)`.
But when I run the same spreadsheet with the absolute  frequencies of the variables **(able = 2, almost = 2 etc)**, the KMO test goes to `0.836`.
I can not proceed without the normalized frequencies of the variables, otherwise many variables will be overestimated.
In this case, what can I do to improve my KMO?

This is a bigger snippet of my spreadsheet, with the relative frequencies of the varibales:

[image]

And a snippet of the Anti-Image Matrice:

[image]

Comment: Does variable `wordcount` itself enter the FA?

Comment: Oh no, no, @ttnphns, when I perform both EFA (with and without the normalized variable frequencies), I remove it.

Comment: Can you present your data, at least partly, to be able to reproduce your finding? It is a bit weird, so it is worth looking on the data.

Comment: Request Anti-image matrix. Individual-variable KMO values (MSA) are on the diagonal of the corr. anti-image matrix. variables with low MSA (such as below .45) are candidates to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, @ttnphns. I've added a bigger snippet of my spreadsheet and also added a snippet of the Anti-image Matrice. If you think it is not big enough, I can add another one. According to the **< 0.45** drop you mentioned, pratically all variables should be dropped.

Comment: @ttnphns, is there another MSA value I could consider? For example, for the KMO test many researchers consider a .50 acceptable for the rotation solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130699/discussion-between-cygnus-x-1-and-ttnphns).

Comment: look at anti-image _correlation_ matrix diagonal. The data snapshot is ok but better would to present data as text, to be able to play with it.

Comment: @ttnphns, indeed, sorry, I was looking at the covariance matrix, not the correlation matrix! I've removed variable above **.45** and it has worked!! The **KMO** now is **.649**, not thaaaat good, but at least it's possible to run a rotated solution, aha!! thank you very much indeed for your solution!!

Comment: .65 is indeed nice. I don't understand why you are speaking of rotation here. KMO is a topic unrelated to rotation. Anyway, I'm glad things improved by now.

Comment: Hi, @ttnphns!! It's because in linguistics (grammatical) MDA (as proposed by (Biber, 1988)), we need to run an unrotated factor solution, check the KMO value, communalities and the scree plot in search for an optimal number of factors for the rotated solution. My professor here in Brazil developed a lexical MDA and it follows the same basic steps! But in the literature there is nothing about how to deal with a low KMO and you helped me with it! Thank you very much again!